# Pagination in Vuetify with "Next" and "Back" button

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to understand how pagination in Vuetify works. I found that with this simple component I can get basic pagination.

```html
<v-pagination
  v-model="page"
  :length="4"
  circle
/>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Instead of this, I just want two buttons; `Next` and `Back`

For now, I only want to know how to change the view. I do not have any event handlers.

Comment: Is there a specific component like you want in Vuetify? If there is not, faster to make 2 buttons yourself!

Comment: No, any components are fine. I could make two buttons but I also need that `page 1/4` thingy. I am not sure how to achieve that!

Comment: Take your elements and divide it by the number of displayed elements per page.

Comment: Thank you, I still have a small question. When I make 2 buttons myself, it should mimic the pagination. So I should hide those "arrows" and replace page numbers with "Back" and "Next" button. How do I paginate with the custom-made button?

Comment: Depends on how you have/fetch your data. You should probably google how to make a pagination if you're not confident.

Comment: I do not have any data. I just want those clickable buttons, nothing needs to happen. I am learning vue (Nuxt) and wanted to see how to create this type of pagination.

Comment: You want how to make a pagination or how to make those buttons (with CSS)?

Comment: Sorry, if I misused the terms. Yes. I only want those buttons with vuetify (and CSS, if necessary). When I click on "Next", it should change `Page 1/4` to `Page 2/4`. That is all I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have 2 basics buttons and the visual on your question, you can achieve it with a simple button component and some CSS like this (using Vue3)

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const count = ref(0)
</script>

<template>
  Page count: {{ count }}
  <br/>
  <button @click="count--" class="button">minus</button>
  <button @click="count++" style="margin-left: 0.5rem; background-color: blue;" class="button">plus</button>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .button {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: none;
  }
</style>
```

Here is [the result](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-card flat>
              <v-card-text>
                <v-btn
                  color="teal"
                  icon
                  small
                  @click="page > 0 ? page-- : null"
                >
                  <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn color="teal" icon small @click="page++">
                  <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-text>
                {{ page }}
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      page: 0,
      dialog: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```